# How to align this div contents properly?

Tags: css, html, alignment

Here is my layout,

[Summary view http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/2500/yuidtsum.jpg](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/2500/yuidtsum.jpg)

I am using one div and many spans for getting the above view... Look at all the rows ther are not properly aligned...

```
<div class="resultsdiv"><br />
<span style="width:200px;" class="resultName">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span>
<span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;
<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br />
<span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span>
<span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span>
<span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;
<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Address + '</span>
</div>
```

and my css are

```
.resultsdiv
{
    background-color: #FFF;border-top:solid 1px #ddd; height:50px; border-bottom:solid 1px #ddd; padding-bottom:15px; width:450px; 
}
.resultseven { background-color: #EFF1f1; }
.resultshover { background-color: #F4F2F2; cursor:pointer; }

.resultName
{
    font-size:125%;font-weight:bolder;color:#476275;font-family:Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
}
.resultfields
{
    font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;font-family:Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
}
.resultfieldvalues
{
    color:#476275;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
}
```

Any suggestion to get it aligned properly.... Should i use divs insted of spans to get this
properly aligned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough cut of some rewritten HTML and CSS.  I have not tested this, but it should get you close.  Post a screenshot if it doesn't work.

HTML

```
<div class="resultsdiv">
  <div class="name">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</div>
  <div class="category"><span>Category :</span> ' + employee.Desig_Name + '</div>
  <div class="salary_basis"><span>Salary Basis :</span> ' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</div>
  <div class="salary"><span>Salary :</span> ' + employee.FixedSalary + '</div>
  <div class="address"><span>Address :</span> ' + employee.Address + '</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.resultsdiv { color: black }
.resultsdiv span { color: #666 }
.resultsdiv { width: 600px}
.resultsdiv div { float: left }
.resultsdiv .name { width: 230px; padding-right 20px; }
.resultsdiv .category { width: 350px }
.resultsdiv .salary_basis { clear: left; width: 180px; padding-right: 20px }
.resultsdiv .salary { width: 180px; padding-right: 20px }
.resultsdiv .address { width: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, that is the type of data that should be in a table. It's not layout, it's tabular, repeating data.

Comment: I agree. Because you are not adding elements to the data, it would be best to use a table.

Comment: it's not actually tabular data.  could be considered a borderline case.  hold on I'm whipping something up for you.

Comment: use tables when it is appropriate to use tables

Comment: This is an appropriate use of tables, IMO.